# Convert Webpage Slider to Video

Tags: java, selenium

Am Developing the application for convert "Webpage slider images" to Video using Java with Selenium.

Challenge was, I want to "Record the slider as video", it is part of the webpage. How can i record particular web part as video or There is any solution for convert web Element to Video file.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using getUserMedia() for more info refer 
w3.org site at link http://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/